# gookit validate required integer fields not accepting 0

Tags: go

I am using [gookit](https://github.com/gookit/validate) for validating my map

But the problem is For required int fields its not accepting 0

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
        "name":  "inhere",
        "age":   100,
        "oldSt": 1,
        "newSt": 2,
        "email": "some@email.com",
    }

    v := validate.Map(m)
    // v := validate.New(m)
    v.AddRule("age", "required")  //here if the field contains 0 ,the validation fails
```

How to make the validate work with integer fields as required but accepting 0 as well.Please help

Comment: 0 is the default value of a newly created integer , so you assign 0 or not the value will be 0 . may be gookit counting 0 valued int as unassigned int

Comment: Can you include your struct definition and the tags? Your sample code is invalid.